# How should i apply date picker in my chart

Tags: javascript, python, charts, chart.js

I want to change dates dynamically in my chart when I press apply in my date range picker. The dates should be aligned accordingly.below is my code which is wrong, please provide me the code

```
<script>
    $('.daterange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function datepicker_Dates(){
     mixedChart.data.labels=[{% for item in labels6 %}
                  "{{item}}",
                {% endfor %}];
                     mixedChart.update();

    }); </script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In python, Tk doesn't include a date picker widget. There are a couple of Python calendar widgets you could try:

http://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/trunk/ttk-gsoc/samples/ttkcalendar.py

http://effbot.org/zone/wcklib-calendar.htm

try something like that:

```
import Tkinter

import ttkcalendar
import tkSimpleDialog

class CalendarDialog(tkSimpleDialog.Dialog):
    """Dialog box that displays a calendar and returns the selected date"""
    def body(self, master):
        self.calendar = ttkcalendar.Calendar(master)
        self.calendar.pack()

    def apply(self):
        self.result = self.calendar.selection

# Demo code:
def main():
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    root.wm_title("CalendarDialog Demo")

    def onclick():
        cd = CalendarDialog(root)
        print cd.result

    button = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Click me to see a calendar!", command=onclick)
    button.pack()
    root.update()

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```